# Draw Image on canvas on button click not working

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, html5-canvas

I am trying to run this code but on click nothing happens.

I think the main problem is the image loading, because when I try
to draw the image that is loaded from an  tag it works.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="445" height="312"
      style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
      Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    <p><button onclick="myCanvas()">Try it</button></p>
    <script>
      function myCanvas() {
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "~/Images/my-meme.jpg";

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the image `src` is at the correct path? I ran your code locally and it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: @Krohn it still doenst work the path is fine any more suggestions?

Comment: Create a jsFiddle reproducing the issue. That will help others be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wait for the image to load before using it. For example,

```
var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // execute drawImage statements here
}, false);
img.src = 'myImage.png'; // Set source path
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images